# Can I clean up this overly nested JSON with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashtable

I have the following variable (parsed from a JSON object)

```
testdata = {
 "file_data"=>[
  {"id"=>"idvalue","desc"=>[
   {"key"=>"value"}
  ]}
 ]
}
```

There is only one filedata, but instead of starting with a hash, it encases its hash in an array. But this madness doesn't end there: the desc key should contain a hash, but instead it contains a one-object array, which contains a hash.

So to get any data out, I have to write things like

```
puts testdata["file_data"][0]["desc"][0]["key"]
```

What can I do about this excess nesting?

Comment: Why not use what you suggested above?

Comment: Besides being ugly, this excess wrapping makes it harder to use something like Hashie::Mash.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
def clean h
  Hash[h.map{|k,v|
    [k,
     case v 
       when Hash then clean(v)  
       when Array then clean(v.first)  
       else v 
     end
    ]
  }]    
end  

clean testdata
#=> {"file_data"=>{"id"=>"idvalue", "desc"=>{"key"=>"value"}}}
```

Comment: Certainly a recursive cleanup method is what I was thinking, but what if the data contains arrays with real values? Example: `{"file_data"=>[{"id"=>"idvalue","desc"=>[{"key"=>[1,2]}]}]}` This particular bit of code throws an error in that case.

Comment: You would have to define more precisely what should happen in which case then.